# How do you set the maxopenfiles limit in Yosemite?

Tags: launchd, macos

How do you set a soft limit for `maxopenfiles` in Yosemite?

I installed Yosemite last night, and now it's ignoring my settings in my `/etc/launchd.conf` file:

```
$ cat /etc/launchd.conf
limit maxfiles 32768 65536

$ launchctl limit maxfiles
    maxfiles    256            unlimited
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Apple removed support for `/etc/launchd.conf` for security reasons. It no longer exists on a clean Yosemite install.

From the `man launchctl` file:

> `launchctl` no longer has an interactive mode, nor does it accept commands from stdin. The `/etc/launchd.conf` file is no longer consulted for subcommands to run during early boot time; this functionality was removed for security considerations.

Answer (score 4):

I created a `/etc/sysctl.conf` file with the following contents:

```
kern.maxfiles=100000
```

If I run `sysctl kern.maxfiles` after restarting it does show the new value there.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested method for most versions of macOS is to create the property list file (`.pfile`) of a user agent in a [`LaunchAgents` directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311962/22781).

This can be created by the following command:

> `sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /Library/LaunchAgents/com.launchd.maxfiles.plist -c "add Label string com.launchd.maxfiles" -c "add ProgramArguments array" -c "add ProgramArguments: string launchctl" -c "add ProgramArguments: string limit" -c "add ProgramArguments: string maxfiles" -c "add ProgramArguments: string 10240" -c "add ProgramArguments: string unlimited" -c "add RunAtLoad bool true"`

<sup>Documentation page: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).</sup>

Related: [How to persistently control maximum system resource consumption on Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108174/21471)