# Where to find app which opens on startup, but it's not in Users & Groups?

Tags: macos, applications, startup

I've this annoying application popping up on startup (called [ZipCloud](http://www.zipcloud.com)) which seems to be installed without my knowledge (along with other app) and I wanted to get rid of it.

[image: annoying ZipCloud pop-up]

I understand I can [uninstall it](http://support.zipcloud.com/question/110/how-do-i-uninstall-zip-cloud) by dragging the app into Trash. However before doing that, I wanted to understand where the app added it-self to the startup scripts.

I've already checked in [System Preferences (Users & Groups)](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18881), but it's not there. I also check my `/etc/rc.local`. And the app it-self doesn't have any options to get rid of the startup.

What other places I can look to get rid of [unwanted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/201601/22781) startup apps?

Comment: Look in ~/LaunchAgents

Comment: LaunchAgents can be found in /Library/LaunchAgents, you may also want to check /Library/LaunchDaemons

Comment: Sorry ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Comment: @Mark You're correct, found the file at: `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.jdibackup.ZipCloud.autostart.plist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a system is booted, `launchd` startup process launches daemons and agents in the following system-level locations (based on the property list files):

- `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` (system-wide, not writeable when [SIP mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is enabled)
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons` (system-wide)

When a user logs in, a per-user `launchd` is started and it loads the user agents from the property list files found in:

- `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` (system-wide, not writeable when [SIP mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) is enabled)
- `/Library/LaunchAgents` (system-wide)
- `~/Library/LaunchAgents` (user-level)

Source: [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

---

On earlier systems, third party startup items could be also found in `/etc/rc.local` file and `/Library/StartupItems` folder, but with Mac OS X 10.4, startup items are deprecated in favour of `launchd` daemons.

Source: [Old Systems and Technology - Startup Item](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html).